# common configuration for multiple project

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I have a VS2013 solution with multiple projects. I have a Web API project, an MVC project, a Windows Service project, and some more business logic projects.
Now if a connectionstring changes I have to replace it at least in 3 projects.

I want to have a common configuration solution. What is your suggestion to handle this situation?

I made a Configuration project with an App.config file, but it seems ConfigurationManager use always it's applications config file, for example if I'm using this Config project from ASP.NET, then the web.config is the living config file, and not the Class libary's app.config.

Huh, I found a solution. Perhaps the method to link a configuration file into every projects would be good too.

Finally I made a MyConfiguration project. Which is contains just this one class:

```
public static class MyConfiguration
{
    #if(DEBUG)
        public static string ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=CRM;persist security info=True;user id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;
    #else
    public const string ConnectionString = "Data Source=yyyyyyyyy.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=CRM;persist security info=True;user id=yyyyyyyyyyyyy;password=yyyyyyyyyy;multipleactiveresultsets=True;"
    #endif
}
```

I just referenced MyConfiguration into my projects, and it will gives me the correct connectionstring for debug and release configurations.
What do you think?

Comment: As far as I know, ASP.Net uses hierarchical Web.Config files, meaning that you should be able to place one at a shared root.

Comment: In your configuration project; instead of using an `App.Config` file, you could use a `Resource File`. It will be embedded in the Configuration project and you can use `Resources.MyValue` from the Configuration project to retrieve the values. The downside to this is you can't make live changes to that resource file.

Comment: We have several separate projects and sites, and for things common across them all, we use machine.config to house those settings.

Comment: machine.config is often too global, especially for things like connection strings.

Comment: @MattTester - Sure, but if it is common across all applications, doesn't it make sense? Sometimes it's beneficial to look at centralising configuration settings and then only to change them once rather than configure each and every application and risk inconsistencies.

Comment: @MrMoose - All I was pointing out was that not every web application on the machine will want or use the exact same settings. This would be true of databases. Production and Staging on the same box would need different dbs. Just an example. If it's a dedicated machine to these apps then Ok, it's doable.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by lahsrah, you need to use a "Add as Link" for the configuration file. However, there is an extra trick as you don't want to share *all* of the config between all the projects.

By using the `configSource` attribute on a configuration section, it is possible to break up a configuration file into smaller files:

- Create a common config file called `ConnectionString.config`. This would be just the connectionStrings config section.
- Add that file as a linked file in each project (using "Add as Link" option). I like to keep it in subfolder called `Config`.
- Use that file in your main config (App.config/Web.config) file using a `configSource` attribute

**ConnectionString.config:**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CustomerCorrespondenceContext" connectionString="Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; Integrated
Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Web.config:**

```
<connectionStrings configSource="Config\ConnectionStrings.config" />
```

**Edit**

Based on the comments, it's worth highlighting that this answers the question on how to make the `connectionStrings` consistent within the solution. Using the "Add as Link" option **makes a copy of the config file when building**, so every project is referencing a local copy of the file, *not* the same file. Therefore, it's not something to help control a deployed environment where changing one file will magically update all apps (that's a different question, with varying options).

So, this is for making the VS Solution manageable for shared configuration between projects of any type.

Comment: Are you sure, that this would be working for very different kind of projects, like windows service, web service, and ASP.NET application? They are running in different places, with different credentials, different permissions on the same server.

Comment: Yes this works regardless of the type of project. The "Add as Link" in VS actually does make a copy of the file when it builds. So when you're using the `configSource` it's a local config file it's loading. So it's a build time convenience, not controlling a deployed environment thing. I'll update the answer to make that clear.

Comment: @matronx Updated the answer. Let me know if the benefits are not clear, etc. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use custom config sections and config handlers. See this 3-part series on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com):

- [*Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)
- [*Decoding the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16724/Decoding-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)
- [*Cracking the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)

Or (even easier), use some variation of Craig Andera's brilliant insight: *The Last Configuration Section Handler You'll Ever Need*:

- https://sites.google.com/site/craigandera/craigs-stuff/clr-workings/the-last-configuration-section-handler-i-ll-ever-need
- http://haacked.com/archive/2004/06/24/verylastconfigurationsectionhandler.aspx/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2005/02/12/371588.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7548/The-very-last-Configuration-Section-Handler-I-hope

This approach is a very generic config section handler. You basically create an XML-serialize class with strongly-type properties and his handler takes care of deserializing the config section into that class. Brilliant!

Once you've done that, your custom config section can be stored externally using the `configSource` attribute. In your config file, where you'd normally do something like this:

```
<config>
  <configSections>
    <section name="myCustomSettings" type="...my-custom-type-spec..." />
  </configSections>
  ...
  <myCustomSettings>
    ...<!-- some custom xml -->
  </myCustomSettings>
  ...
<config>
```

You'll do something like this to tell the .Net config system to load that section from the specified external file:

```
<config>
  <configSections>
    <section name="myCustomSettings" type="...my-custom-type-spec..." />
  </configSections>
  ...
  <myCustomSettings configSource="\foo\bar\baz\myCustomSettings.config.xml" />
  ...
<config>
```

The external file is an XML document: the root node has to be the section name just as if it had been cut wholesale from the config file.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myCustomSettings>
  ...
</myCustomSettings>
```

Now, all you have to do is propagate the required standalone config files to where the different applications expect to find them.

It should be noted that the external file located by the `configSource` attribute has to be local to that machine: it can't live on the network.

And, put some smarts in your config section handler and it can wire up a file system watcher to monitor that file for changes and reload without restarting the app, though you'll need to add the attribute `restartOnExternalChanges="false"` to the `<section>` to prevent the app restart first.

Sweet!

Comment: This seems a little outdated for me. I think this could be work, but I'm sure that there must be a fresh better solution for solving debug, release automation, working for very different kind of projects.

Comment: It's a nice idea for a deployed environment, but it's overkill for simply managing the solution configs.

Comment: Distributed/Shared configuration is and always has been a hassle. .Net configuration hasn't changed much since it's .Net 2.0 remodel. You can certainly write custom config section handlers the .Net way (the MSFT-recommended practice), but it's an awful lot of boilerplate code to write. And once it's done, IMHO, the notation used to access the section properties is...sub-optimal.

The generic config section handler has the advantage of making it much easier to crank out a custom section. And, as a side benefit, the rehydrated object gives you much cleaner notation to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Add the file "As a Link" to the second project and you will use the same file for both.[image]

If you need to have project specific settings as well then create a child app.config file and add it as a link to all your projects and make all your project app.config/web.config files inherit from this linked file.  Put your common settings in the linked file.